# How do you get the "dim amount" of a Window?

Tags: android, user-interface, window, material-design

Android has a Window class that lets us set the dim amount behind the window.

```
public void setDimAmount (float amount)
```

While there is the "set" function, there isn't a "get" function for checking the existing dim amount.

Could someone let me know how I can "get" or find out the existing or default dim amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WindowManager.LayoutParams` holds the attributes for window . A quick loop up at source code could help.

```
 public void setDimAmount(float amount) {
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getAttributes();
    attrs.dimAmount = amount;
    mHaveDimAmount = true;
    dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(attrs);
}
```

So when you want to get the `dimAmount` you can just get it from `WindowManager.LayoutParams`.

```
float dimAmount = getWindow().getAttributes().dimAmount;
```